# Euler angles transformation failed in this case

Tags: math, unity-game-engine, 3d

I tried Euler angles transformation in this case, but I could not find the correct sequence of xyz to get target orientation.

P.S. I am following the convention of x->y->z for Euler angles transformation.

P.S. Euler angles transformation: each rotation takes place relative to original frame.

[image]

The rotation of z axis can only switch y and x, but it won't lead to final target. 
What is the right way?

final answer:

[image]

@Rooscannon, thanks you very much!

Comment: If you want to get the target from the result of 2 rotations (rotate x - 90) and rotate y+45, all you need to rotate around Y axis by 90 degree.

Comment: your bottom rotation is incorrect. that is a rotation about z by 45. the final step would be a rotation about y by 90. switching these two steps will still give you the same result

Comment: for euler, isn't the next rotation after x and y,  is rotation around z axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotate (45, 180 , 90)
Here the maths
http://www.staff.city.ac.uk/~sbbh653/publications/euler.pdf

getting the rotation matrix is very simple in your use case. The columns of the 3X3 rotation matrix are the rotated unit vectors x,y,z in the new position. For example x was originally (1,0,0) and after rotation (0,-1,0). y = (-sqrt(2)/2, 0, -sqrt(2)/2), z = ( sqrt(2)/2, 0, -sqrt(2)/2).
So your rotation matrix will be something like

```
        0   -0.7   0.7
 R =   -1    0     0 
        0   -0.7  -0.7
```

Use exact values though. If insecure the determinant should be 1 and the norm of each column and row should be 1.

Comment: yes, this set of rotation in xyz order leads to the answer of correct R. But the ref link is how to decompose a R matrix in xyz, I wonder how to know the R matrix in first place? thanks.

Comment: i cannot draw diagram to visualize (45, 180 , 90), the rotation of 45 degree around x is complex, is it possible that you can show me how? thanks.

Comment: Added info how to derive the rotation matrix. I don't know what do you mean by a complex rotation. If you rotate x-axis by 45 degrees to positive direction your down ward looking graph will show z-axis  shortened by a factor of 0.7 and y-axis emerging as the opposite of z.

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

Rotate 135 on `y`. And then rotate -90 on `z` to get the desired angel.

Your final rotation will be :

```
(0,135,-90)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: unable to rotate it to desired angle. https://imgur.com/eUDjv7U  what i made wrong?

Comment: i found i can do the rotation z -90 then y 135, then done. but what if i want to follow xyz convention? thanks.

Comment: In your desired angle, you don't have to rotate on x, So apparently you are following xyz convention: x=0,y=135,z=-90. :)